# Conversion of Javascript Code to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, caching

I am trying to extend the mongoose query function to enable me append a cache function to a mongoose query. I have done the javascript implementation but run into different errors when I try to implement it in typescript

the Javascript code is;

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
const redisClient = require('./RedisClient');

mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function (options = {}) {
  this.useCache = true;
  this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || '');
  return this;
}

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
  if (!this.useCache) {
    return exec.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  const key = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this.getFilter(), {
    collection: this.mongooseCollection.name
  }));

  const cachedValue = await redisClient.getHCache(this.hashKey, key);

  if (cachedValue) {
    const doc = JSON.parse(cachedValue);
    return Array.isArray(doc)
      ? doc.map(d => new this.model(d))
      : new this.model(doc);
  }

  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);
  await redisClient.setHCache(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));


  return result;
}
```

my typescript implementation is

```
import mongoose, { Query } from 'mongoose';
import RedisClient  from './redisClient';

declare module 'mongoose' {
  interface Query<T> {
    useCache?: boolean;
    hashKey?: string;
    cache(options?: { key?: unknown }): Query<T>;
  }
}

const exec = Query.prototype.exec;

Query.prototype.cache = function (options = {}): Query<any> {
  this.useCache = true;
  this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || '');
  return this;
};

Query.prototype.exec = async function (): Promise<any> {
  if (!this.useCache) {
    return exec.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  const key = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this.getFilter(), {
    collection: this.mongooseCollection.name,
  }));

  const cachedValue = await RedisClient.getHCache(this.hashKey, key);

  if (cachedValue) {
    const doc = JSON.parse(cachedValue);
    return Array.isArray(doc)
      ? doc.map((d: any) => new this.model(d))
      : new this.model(doc);
  }

  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);
  await RedisClient.setHCache(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));

  return result;
};
```

The errors I am getting are;

> All declarations of 'Query' must have identical type parameters.

> Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'

> Property 'mongooseCollection' does not exist on type 'Query<any, any, any, any, any, any>'. Did you mean 'mongooseOptions'?

please assist

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way to do this, also explaining the reasons for the changes -

```ts
declare module "mongoose" {
    // For the declaration merging to work, any existing declaration from the module needs to be declared exactly the same
    // which is why `interface Query<T>` doesn't work and you have to make the declaration identical to declaration from the library itself
    // Query<T> {
    interface Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers = {}, RawDocType = DocType, QueryOp = "find"> {
        useCache?: boolean;
        hashKey?: string;
        cache(options?: { key?: unknown }): Query<ResultType, DocType, THelpers, RawDocType, QueryOp>;
    }
}

const exec = Query.prototype.exec;

Query.prototype.cache = function (options = {}) {
    this.useCache = true;
    this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || '');
    return this;
}


Query.prototype.exec = async function (): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.useCache) {
        // No need to pass `arguments` as the exec doesn't take any arguments per function signature
        // The type of arguments is IArguments in typescript by default, and when there's no arguments,
        // the type inferred is [], i.e., an empty array hence the error: Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'
        // return exec.apply(this, arguments);
        return exec.apply(this);
    }

    const key = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, this.getFilter(), {
        // this.mongooseCollection is used internally by the Query [1], and although it's added in the redis
        // cache setup guide (which is quite old, and was written 4 years ago [2], and the official typescript bindings came later on [3][4]), it's not available for use through API
        // access collection from the model itself.
        // [1] https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/865887862721689aa1fa6657af2d9b17e001a82e/lib/query.js#L111
        // [2] https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blame/865887862721689aa1fa6657af2d9b17e001a82e/examples/redis-todo/services/cache.js#L22
        // [3] https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html#typescript-support
        // [4] https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5110--2020-11-30
        // collection: this.mongooseCollection.name,
        collection: this.model.collection.name,
    }));

    const cachedValue = await RedisClient.getHCache(this.hashKey, key);

    if (cachedValue) {
        const doc = JSON.parse(cachedValue);
        return Array.isArray(doc)
            ? doc.map((d: any) => new this.model(d))
            : new this.model(doc);
    }
    // No need to pass `arguments` as the exec doesn't take any arguments per function signature
    // The type of arguments is IArguments in typescript by default, and when there's no arguments,
    // the type inferred is [], i.e., an empty array hence the error: Argument of type 'IArguments' is not assignable to parameter of type '[]'
    // const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);
    const result = await exec.apply(this);
    await RedisClient.setHCache(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));

    return result;
};
```

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=63&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCCA7A5hCBnApgGjgbzgEUBXLKATzgF84AzKCEOAIkVXWxYG4AoXgPQC4AZRgkARnAAmWAMYAbAIZQlMYMl6zFKrHDnIM8AEpZpwDAGEFwLEhgAuAnBRYYACUtK5ACyxOACh8lDB8AaSwKJxIkAGskCAB3JDxYyOi4hOSASjgAXgA+OCUkCjxsDy9ffzggkPD0uBj4pJS4NKimzNa8OW8-DJac-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-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-UOj1lRtzABgBwQg7gQkkFBAwIABAjRIE8EAagjQCAdpwLAAhsYQAkAIAAHAANgAKzUOoQAdjoUPZhQ8Q60OoQATiUEoEObJaEMOYUoOgQ9pA8IkCHZhWAAAMciQ5KGoUPMh9oBCVy5FBVWGAADEAAZEORjYEjwQTAJBKCBBoJ8BgrBOC8FMEIVSYh6xSHkOUMSGhDCmGsNoewzh3C+ECKESIsREipEyPkYo5RqiBBYnACsDAAgM4YAALRPGygIbAUBRhUhFAIHO2i9H6KHkPWB+8zEWKECQzYOjMFMAENlOQSTobz2ANuKCPgYAgAULo1pc12kwFSZGBm0AYCwKPpU5BqDq42IkPU7BuD8FOLkC4jgmx3GUOISEQmAhLDuBGvxAA4gAUX0fWI59tpC6PoUYuRqTUlDzkU81JRjUm7zkd-AwLsNZXCcP5GpTsflu2QFBBqxJjo230IA35yB-mUmkuAhQ9TgU7jBUSXAAYzwcwDOLeAOdpAADUo5kHMk3aucBTDmCsDYQ0UFjaeAYszBFnT6gzlSJEHFXleoBAJcShQZBgpQrxUKayPE+KCTxtgXlDEiUkqwMLG2XNrhjV+lBCwqqlDiSadkE63Z+yivtvTAIARpBOE+LkQocIsCJDtki012RdVQu7E4eEtqAXQizKa5Mir-wBkOOFa1UVcaxTgPFNmKU0pInOllHK4p4AwAKrKKgCVDrlUqvhaq7sMYNQ0iSbshx2pqgrMTVNCNkZw3BuVNO-SF6LWWlgVa5sG6bS0n4Hae1nhloGpC0KGVoaBmulAW6tInovTeh9LAX0U3Dq1cqOwf8MrAygKDCN8AeokyUpWtNiNkYXzRjmu+apnh4wxVvDdA6xRk39dnQw8B5iRnNmSm+YFeZyH5ozcSLMDoI19dC0CcAH1RmfRS2m9NP3MosH+ksL7KVmAsNYWw9ghJuEZRufyHF2WSzKHAGWglhKKzEgEID5tHWoW7MqwDIooy6W4EAA) to playground.